# Oracle by default User names and passwords

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

i installed oracle 10g,but after installing it when i came to sql+ and entered default username and password that is  **SCOTT & TIGER** it says the account is locked,
i even tried with my password which i entered at a time of installation.

Answer (score 1):

login as SYS user and unlock the account

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
alter user scott account unlock;
conn scott/tiger
```